# Check the format of a string

Tags: java, pattern-matching

I need build a method to check if a string has the following format:

`[{...},{...},...,{...}]`

But I'm not sure what is the best/simpler approach to do this. Should I iterate through the string or can I use Pattern/Matcher classes?

Some suggestion or piece of code to start with would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

The problem is that the string can come in the wrong format so the method sould return an error... Next, I show some examples that what can come and what should be returned:

`[{...},{...},{...}]` --> return VALID;

`[{...},{...}]` --> return VALID;

`[{...},{...},{...},{...}]` --> return VALID;

`[...},{...},{...},{...}]` --> return ERROR;

`[{...},{...}{...}]` --> return ERROR;

`[{...},{...},{...},{...}` --> return ERROR;

`[{...,{...},{...},{...}]` --> return ERROR;

`[{...},{...},,{...}]` --> return ERROR;

`[asd{...},{...},{...},{...}]` --> return ERROR;

Comment: You can use regular expressions!

Comment: What about nested braces?

Comment: Regular expressions seem like a good solution here, check out the java.util.regex library: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Comment: It would depend how the `String` can come. If it's as easy as you put it, just use a RegEx, it is too complicated to parse (like an XML file) create your own parser by iterating through the `String`. By the way it looks, it can be a JSON `String`, if this is the case you should not parse it yourself instead use a dedicated library.

Comment: @thatidiotguy not everything can be parsed with regular expressions =\

Comment: @thatidiotguy,@SLaks,@RainbowFish,@Luiggi Mendoza Check my edit please. I added some examples that what could be the string... I'm not sure if I can use regex to do this...

Comment: @amp You can use regular expressions to do this. You need to learn regular expressions though. Most people don't memorize them, they go look up a tutorial and write them as needed. This is what you are going to have to learn to do.

Comment: are your "..." expressions literally three dots, or shorthand for "any number of characters"?

Comment: @KevinWelker It's any number of characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED** to reflect dots representing arbitrary strings that do not contain '[', ']', or '{'

```
String regex = "\\[\\{[^\\[\\]{]*}(,\\{[^\\[\\]{]*})*]";
```

If this looks daunting, it is probably due more to Java String character escaping than the regular expression itself.  Without all the escapes (required) it would look like:

```
\[\{[^\[\]{]*}(,\{[^\[\]{]*})*]
```

And to clarify even more by space separating the logical groupings:

```
\[   \{[^\[\]{]*}   (,\{[^\[\]{]*})*   ]
```

The first and last characters are literal matches of the opening/closing '[' and ']'.  The second character indicates a required opening literal '{', and is followed by a character class expression representing an arbitray (zero or more) number of characters other than '[', ']', or '{', and finally followed by the closing literal '}' of the first curly-bracketed grouping in the source string.

However there **may** be additional curly-braced groupings afterwards, so the parenthesized expression repeats the first one with a preceding literal comma, and this whole expression may be repeated zero or more times.

So if this makes it any easier to read or maintain, you could express it in code as follows:

```
String subgrp = "\\{[^\\[\\]{]*}";
String optionalRepeatSubgrp = "(," + subgrp + ")*";

String regex = "\\[" + subgrp + optionalRepeatSubgrp + "]";
```

Comment: Awsome answer! Thanks a lot for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to solve most of the problem, however as I am not quite good at negative lookahead I was not able to crack the only case that fails below

This code

1. Recursilvely replaces the `{*},` pattern with empty string
2. Then replaces the last `{*}` with empty string
3. The remaining if matches with `[]` then the string is said to be valid or else not.

Hope you get what I am trying to do here.

```
public static boolean isValid(String input){

        // Iterates and replaces all but one substring that match {...},
        boolean replaced = true;
        int oldLength=0, newLength=0;
        while(replaced){
            oldLength=input.length();
            input = input.replaceFirst("\\{[a-z.]+},", "");
            newLength=input.length();
            if(oldLength==newLength)    replaced=false;
        }

        // Replaces the last {...} 
        // This one is done separately as comma should not be present in the last part 
        input = input.replaceFirst("\\{.*?}", "");

        //Then if the string remaining is just [] then it is valid
        if(input.equals("[]")){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] input = {"[{...},{...},{...}]",
                            "[{...},{...}]",
                            "[{...},{...},{...},{...}]",
                            "[...},{...},{...},{...}]",
                            "[{...},{...}{...}]",
                            "[{...},{...},{...},{...}",
                            "[{...,{...},{...},{...}]",
                            "[{...},{...},,{...}]",
                            "[asd{...},{...},{...},{...}]"
                    };
        for (String s : input) {
            if(isValid(s)){
                System.out.println("VALID");
            } else {
                System.out.println("ERROR");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This outputs -

```
VALID
VALID
VALID
ERROR
ERROR
ERROR
VALID
ERROR
ERROR
```

So it's the 3rd last case not being handled correctly i.e.

```
 [{...,{...},{...},{...}]
```

This does require the negative lookahead i.e. The regex `{*},` should not match a `{` if it comes after `{` and before `}`.

Answer (score 0):

Why just not iterate over the string instead of spending time to think complex regular expression?

```
public boolean isValid(String str){
        if( !str.startsWith("[") || !str.endsWith("]") )
            return false;

        if( 1 < str.length() - 2 )
            return false;

        str = str.substring(1, str.length() - 2);

        String[] array = str.split(",");
        String part;

        for( int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i ++ ){
            part = array[i];

            if(!part.startsWith("{") || !part.endsWith("}"))
                return false;

            if( 1 < part.length() - 2 )
                return false;

            part = part.substring(1, part.length() - 2);

            if(part.contains("{") || part.contains("}"))
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: hmmm... which is more complex? The one line regex or 20 lines of code with 6 returns?

Comment: If You don't know regex sure that this is more simpler :)

Comment: Certainly, but if you don't know regex then you will be pretty crippled in most languages and scripts.  So it is worthwhile to learn at least the basics.